# Probability and partition rule usage

Tags: probability

I'm answering a question on probability

> A warehouse contains packs of electronic components. Forty percent of
>   the packs contain components of low quality for which the probability
>   that any given component will prove satisfactory is 0.8; forty percent
>   contain components of medium quality for which this probability is
>   0.9; and the remaining twenty percent contain high quality components which are certain to be satisfactory.

The first part of the question asked to me

> If a pack is chosen at random and one component from it is tested,
>   what is the probability that this component is satisfactory?

Where I managed to get this part of the question by using the partition rule

$L = $ low quality

$M = $ medium quality

$H = $ high quality

$S = $ Satisfactory

$ P(S) = P(S|L) \times P(L) + P(S|M) \times P(M) + P(S|H) \times P(H)$

$ = 0.8 \times 0.4 + 0.9 \times 0.4 + 1 \times 0.2 $

$ = 0.88 $

And I'm trying to answer this question which says

> If a pack is chosen at random and two components from it are tested,
>   what is the probability that exactly one of the components tested is
>   satisfactory?

My thoughts were that all I needed to find was $P(S)P(\overline{S}) + P(\overline{S})P(S)$ which is one component is satisfactory. But why does this give me the incorrect answer? Am I misunderstanding something here?

$ 2 \times 0.88 \times (1 - 0.88) = 0.2112$

I checked the answer and it's just different to what I expected; the partition rule was used here and they got 0.2 as the answer.

I'm a bit confused at what to do here.

Comment: The problem with your method (in part $2$) is that the events are not independent.  Knowing whether the first component failed (or not) tells you a lot about the second.

Comment: How do I know if they are independent or not?

Comment: If the first one fails, that increases the probability that you chose the Low Quality pack (and you know for certain that you did not chose the High Quality pack). Take a caricature example:  suppose all the samples in pile $A$ fail, and all the samples in pile $B$ pass.  You randomly pick a pile and test two...what is the probability that they both pass?  The answer is $\frac 12$ (not $\frac 14$) since the only issue is which pile you chose.